# Azure Auth InvalidAuthenticationToken - CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049217

Tags: azure, react-native, authentication, token

I'm new to React Native and I'm trying to implement Microsoft authentication through this [library](https://github.com/renzsans/react-native-azure-ad-auth) but something is not working.

This is a very tiny library with an apparently super easy implementation.

These are my credentials:

```
  const credentials = {
    authority: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${AuthConfig.tenantId}`,
    client_id: AuthConfig.appId,
    client_secret: AuthConfig.secret,
    redirect_uri: "http://localhost:8081/",
    scope: AuthConfig.appScopes,
  };
```

So, with the `returnURI` set to be `http://localhost:8081`, the app redirects correctly after successful auth, and both token + user data are returned, which makes me think that at least my credentials are correct.

However, if I set the `returnURI` to `"com.msgraph://oauth/redirect/"`, Azure returns this:

```
{"error": {"code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken", "innerError": {"client-request-id": "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXX", "date": "2022-10-14T07:27:30", "request-id": "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXX"}, "message": "CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049217"}}
```

and an error message saying

```
Error: Could not open URL 'com.msgraph://oauth/redirect/?code=0.ATkAbbMV87Ls8UuRKyUe8...... etc
```

I also tried redirecting to `"msauth://com.msgraph/<signature HASH>"`, same result though.

This is how I have configured the URI on the Azure Portal:

[image]
[image]

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!!

Comment: If you are developing with Android, have you setup the `appAuthRedirectScheme` in build.gradle (app) file?

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying! In my `app/build.gradle` I have `manifestPlaceholders = [appAuthRedirectScheme: 'com.redirectScheme.comm']` (under `defaultConfig`). Apart from that, I have no other `appAuthRedirectScheme` occurrencies in the whole repo. Is that what your were mentioning above?

Comment: If you are using Azure auth, Azure will return token to you by deep link which the format of the link should start with "msauth". So, in my experience, you should use `appAuthRedirectScheme: 'msauth'`. Otherwise, the app will not notice that is a valid return link for the app.

Comment: Hi, I can confirm I have `manifestPlaceholders = [appAuthRedirectScheme: 'msauth']` in the `build.gradle`, and `redirect_uri: "com.msgraph://oauth/authorize/",` in my credentials, but unfortunately still hitting `CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049217"`

Comment: Do you add any token to the header when fetching? See the support doc [here](https://blogs.aaddevsup.xyz/2022/08/receiving-error-compacttoken-parsing-failed-when-calling-microsoft-graph/).